# left Rotate algorithm binary value in c

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to left rotate binary value:

```
int left_side=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {         
        left_side = left_side | (  ( number & ( 1<<BITS-i )) >> (BITS+i+1)-n  );

    }
```

`BITS` indicates the length of the binary value, n is the distance for rotation.
Example: 1000 , and n=1 which means the solution will be: 0001.

Some reason that I don't understand when I rotate it (from left to right side), lets take an example for number 253 which in binary sequence is 11111101 and n=3 (distance), the result from my code in binary sequence is 101 (which is 5).
Why the answer isn't 7? What I missed in my condition in this loop?
Thanks.

Comment: also don't forget that you are trying to shift a **signed** int. Take attentiot to the sign bit. Didn't you want to use an `unsigned int`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your faulty result `left_side = 5`. For me, the result is `left_side = 1` (which is also wrong). [Try it yourself](https://onlinegdb.com/B1Tb4M_zP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are 2 approaches:

1. rotate by 1 bit `n` times
2. rotate by `n % BITS` bits only once

The rotation "wraps over" so we could just modulo every BITSth (8th) multiple of `n` to 0 in case someone would want to rotate 100 times. I think the second approach would be easier to understand, implement and read and why loop 100 times, if it can be done once?

### Algorithm:

I will use 8 bits for demonstration, even though [int is minimum 16 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types). The original MSB is marked by a dot.

`.11110000 rl 2 == 110000.11`

Well what has happened? `2` bits went right and the rest (`BITS - 2`) went left. That is just shift left and shift right "combined".

```
a = .11110000 << 2 == 110000.00
b = .11110000 >> (BITS - 2) == 000000.11
c = a | b
c == 110000.11
```

Easy, isn't it? Just remember to use `n % BITS` first and to use an `unsigned` type.

```c
unsigned int rotateLeft(unsigned int number, int n) {
    n %= BITS;
    unsigned int left = number << n;
    unsigned int right = number >> (BITS - n);
    return left | right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the same logic applys with signed int ?

Comment: No, accroding to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Right_shift_%3E%3E "When performed on a signed type, the result is technically undefined and compiler dependent, however most compilers will perform an arithmetic shift, causing the blank to be filled with the sign bit of the left operand."

So usually negative numbers will retain the 1 in the MSB thus polluting everything when shifting. I am sure you don't want this.

Answer (score 2):

You want to rotate left your number `n` of a specific `amount` of bits.

Thus you have to shift your number to the left using `n << amount` and put the left bits to the right. This is done by putting the bits `[0-amount[` to [NUMBER_BITS-amount,NUMBER_BITS[` using right shift.

For instance, if your number is an `uint32_t` you can use the following code (or easily adapt it to other types).

```c
uint32_t RotateLeft(uint32_t n, int amount)  { 
    return (n << amount)|(n >> (8*sizeof(uint32_t) - amount)); 
}
```